# Laravel 4 dependencies

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I'm getting the following error with composer update:

```
Installation request for internations/http-mock dev-master -> satisfiable by internations/http-mock[dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: jeremeamia/SuperClosure[2.0.x-dev, 1.0.1].
    - internations/http-mock dev-master requires jeremeamia/superclosure ~2 -> satisfiable by jeremeamia/superclosure[2.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for jeremeamia/superclosure 1.0.1 as dev-master -> satisfiable by jeremeamia/SuperClosure[1.0.1].
```

I can't update to superclosure 2.0 because laravel 4 throws an error and required 1.0.*

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use code that uses Superclosure 1.0, then either you update that code to use version 2.0, or you can't update. Composer cannot help you with that, it simply makes it obvious that there is this conflict.

However, I notice that you are using branches. Please don't! It creates lots of pains with update conflicts, because basically you cannot rewind a branch back to a previous commit that once worked with your other packages when you update. The update will simply refuse to work anymore.

ALWAYS INSTALL TAGGED VERSIONS! Optimally you use software that sticks to semantic versioning (see http://semver.org for details of what this is), and then make an updateable version requirement like `~1.0` (install 1.0.0 or any later update and compatible release, but not 2.0, because thats incompatible according to semver) or `^1.0.3` (install at least 1.0.3 because the previous versions had bugs, and allow compatible updates, but not version 2.0).